# file_get_contets redirecionar usuário para url random

Tags: php

```
<?php

$Arquivos = glob('artis/*.txt');
$ArquivoEscolhido = $Arquivos[rand(0,  count($Arquivos) - 1)];
$Linhas = file($ArquivoEscolhido);
$LinhaEscolhida = $Linhas[rand(0,  count($Linhas) - 1)];

$url = $LinhaEscolhida;

$url = str_replace(' ','',$url);

$vai = file_get_contents($url);

echo $vai;

?>
```

Ele busca na pasta um arquivo txt (com várias urls dentro) de forma random e escolhe uma linha dentro deste arquivo e apresenta url.

Dentro desta url (.html) existem várias outras urls entre:

```
<li class="ohyeah">

</li>
```

Detalhes:

Eu tenho vários arquivos txt dentro de uma pasta

```
/pasta/1.txt
/pasta/2.txt
```

Dentro desses arquivos contém várias urls

```
Exemplo:
/pasta/1.txt
conteúdo:
www.site.com/nome/jose.html
www.site.com/nome/joao.html


/pasta/2.txt
conteúdo:
www.site.com/nome/maria.html
www.site.com/nome/juliana.html
```

conteúdo da página .html

```
<li class="ohyeah">
<a href="http://www.site.com.br/nome/maria"> maria </a>
<a href="http://www.site.com.br/nome/joga"> joao </a>
(e várias outras)
</li>
```

No código eu já consigo buscar a url dentro dos arquivos .txt de forma random.

Agora eu preciso acessar essa url (dentro de $url) pegar o conteúdo da página (escolhida de forma random) e capturar uma única url (de várias) dentro de:

```
<li class="ohyeah">

</li>
```

Comment: Qual o objetivo disso? Por quê tantos redirecionamentos?

Comment: Joga tudo para um array, e depois faz um array_rand

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, para um sistema de compartilhamento de URL. O conteúdo do site não é salvo em banco de dados então para eu capturar as urls da forma que preciso... é o jeito mais fácil que encontrei.

Comment: @Everson, não tenho conhecimento suficiente. Consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta para facilitar.. um momento.

Comment: Posta aqui o conteudo html com as urls para poder te ajudar. Edita sua Pergunta para manter a coesão !

Comment: @RafaelSalomão, feito!

Comment: Sinceramente, eu ainda não entendi. Todas as os arquivos `.txt` possuem uma URL, e dentro de cada URL possui uma referencia a um `.html` e nesse HTML, todos eles possuem a tag `<li class="ohyeah">` ?

Comment: @Everson, exato. Eu já consigo a URL dentro do arquivo txt. Agora eu preciso buscar UM única url dentro da tag <li e redirecionar o usuário para ela.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nessa linha do seu código  `$url = str_replace(' ','',$url);` retorna um url random de um dos arquivos `txt` do diretório  `pasta` como por exemplo `www.site.com/nome/juliana.html`

Logo após você usa  `file_get_contents;` cuja finalidade é ler o conteúdo de um arquivo. Só que você está tentando ler o conteúdo de um url  `file_get_contents($url);` visto que `$url` retorna por exemplo `www.site.com/nome/juliana.html` e **isso vai gerar apenas um erro** e nada mais.

```
Warning:  file_get_contents(www.site.com/nome/juliana.html): 
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in .....
```

Portanto retire essa linha do seu código que não serve para nada além de gerar um  `Warning`.

Se você já tem um url random para fazer o redirecionamento, não entendi o porque da lista de urls

```
<li class="ohyeah">
  .............
  .............
</li>
```

Você deve ter lá suas razões e portanto para fazer isso pode usar o código abaixo.

```
$conteudoLista="";
$arr="";
$i=1;
$pasta = 'pasta/';
$diretorio = dir($pasta);
while($arquivo = $diretorio -> read()){
    if (file_exists($pasta.$i.".txt")) {
        $f = file($pasta.$i.".txt");
            foreach($f as $item){
               $arr .= $item .",";
               $strDir = str_replace(".html","",$item); 
               $nome = substr($strDir, 18);
               $conteudoLista .="<a href='http://".$item."'>".$nome."</a><br>"; 
               $conteudoLista = preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $conteudoLista );
            }
    }
$i=$i+1;
}
$diretorio -> close();

$enderecos = (substr($arr,0,-1)); 
$partes = explode(',',$enderecos);
$qtd = count($partes);
$numRnad = (rand(1,$qtd));
$result=$partes[$numRnad];

echo "<li class=\"ohyeah\">".$conteudoLista."</li>";
echo "<br>";
echo "link random : ".$result;
```

> **Explicando:**

`$pasta = 'pasta/'` - caminho relativo do diretório

`dir()` - Com essa função, iremos ler o diretório pasta e, com o uso do método read(), vamos listar todos os arquivos existentes nesse diretório.

`$diretorio = dir($pasta)` - ler o diretório

`while($arquivo = $diretorio -> read())` - iteração para percorrer os arquivos listando-os com o método read()

`if (file_exists($pasta.$i.".txt"))` - fazer uma verificação para saber se o arquivo existe

`foreach($f as $item)` - iteração em que $item recebe o valor de cada item do array

`$arr .= $item .","` - concatenando cada item separado por virgula

`str_replace` - para retirar (substituir) a extensão .html dos urls

`substr($strDir, 18)` - Extrair uma parte de uma string - retorna a parte do url da posição 18 até o final, ou seja, elimina - www.site.com/nome/ - que é comum a todas os urls

`preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $conteudoLista )` - realiza uma pesquisa por uma expressão regular e a substitui - \n quebra de linha e \r retorno de carro

`substr($arr,0,-1)` - retirando a última virgula de $arr

`$partes = explode(',',$enderecos)`- Vamos separar a string $enderecos em todas as ocorrências de virgula

`$qtd = count($partes)`- obter o número de elementos que compõem o array $partes

`$numRnad = (rand(1,$qtd))` - gera um numero aleatorio entre 1 e a quantidade de elementos do array $partes

`$result=$partes[$numRnad]` - retorna o valor da posição $numRnad do array $partes

`$diretorio -> close()` - fechamos a leitura

Documentação utilizada

- [dir()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.dir.php)
- [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-exists.php)
- [foreach](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php)
- [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php)
- [substr](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php)
- [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-replace.php)
- [explode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php)
- [rand](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.rand.php)

Answer (score 1):

A forma mais simples e elegante de fazer :

é ler esse html com doom:

```
<li class="ohyeah">
    <a href="http://www.site.com.br/nome/maria"> maria </a>
    <a href="http://www.site.com.br/nome/joga"> joao </a>
</li>

$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile("https://url selecionada");
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query("//li[@class='ohyeah']");
foreach ($nodes as $i => $node) {
   echo "Node($i): ", $node->nodeValue, "\n";
}
```

depois filtre esse bloco e pegar as urls com essa expressão regular do xpath em seguida percorrendo os nós com um loop você obtem as urls.
É evidente que esse código está incompleto a solução é mais cabeluda um pouquinho ia demorar um tempo para escrever. Mas te passei todo o conceito.